# iOS Development: Use of GameCenter advised to reach a sizeable audience? Performance questions?

Tags: networking, ios, gamekit, game-center, multiplayer

I've started to plan out a simple game for iOS that would include a multiplayer component. Taking quick look at Game Center, it seems to me that the capabilities that it offers fall right in line with what I have planned.

It would be a hell of a lot easier to develop using this rather than to be responsible for establishing a network, developing server code, having to worry about server communication with various iOS devices, and the like.

However it does, at first glance, seem a bit high level (maybe too high level for my liking?). I'm not used to things looking this easy (especially for something as complicated as online multiplayer gaming, however simple the implementation is). How big of a performance trade-off, if any, would I be expecting if I were to use this instead of developing the multiplayer component completely from the ground up? (Let's say, for example, that the multiplayer activity would be akin to sending small text messages to each other every 1-2 seconds)

More importantly, I would want to reach as large an audience as possible, and I know that Game Center is not available for the 2G and 3G iPhones, as well as the first generation iPod touch. Is the user-base for the collection of these devices large enough that neglecting them would have a sizeable effect on revenue?

I'm sorry these are questions are not directly related to code (I don't know why i'm anticipating 5 SOers barging in here with torches and pitchforks screaming '**INVALID QUESTION**!'...?), however I hope I can get some answers before that happens.

Comment: Yeah the user base is big enough and Apple has already deprecated the 1st generation devices. I would just go with it, I am very confident that Apple has written it to be very optimized. I am also positive they get feedback from Apps using it every day and make changes accordingly

Comment: Plus Apple probably has a higher chance of supporting your app in featured areas and the like if it supports Game Center.

Comment: I'm confused; the user base I was referring to was the combined user base for 3G and 2G iPhones. Are you saying this user base is big enough that I should consider NOT using Game Center, or are you saying that its small enough that I should just develop with Game Center?

Comment: I think @Justin is saying to go ahead and use Game Center and not worry about losing out on compatibility with older devices.

Comment: @Kevin Yes I am saying that the audience of people using game center is large enough to support it and the benefits outweigh the small amount of users that don't have it.

Comment: I found game center integration to be much simpler that doing it all ourselves. The performance is good enough. Apple has indeed made sure that the requests are scalable. And, they have a large enough user base using the devices supporting game center. If you are still looking forward to get a larger user base, you can consider, openfeint too. http://support.openfeint.com/dev/openfeint-api-for-ios-turn-based-multiplayer-implementation-guide/